# Seagate is not allowing me to make partition on MS-DOS (FAT) Or ExFAT!

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, partition, external-disk

I just bought an external hard drive (Seagate Backup Plus Slim 2 TB) for my Mac (Yosemite installed) for professional photography.

I wanted to make partitions for both Mac and Windows, but it only allows for Mac. I think as I tried so many time. So I put Basic device (2 TB) on Mac (Mac OS Extended (Journaled)) and then made two partition, one just for the Mac (Mac OS Extended (Journaled) 500 GB) and main one (photos 1.5 TB) for Mac and PC.

I wanted to connect it to a TV also. But unfortunately it isn't detected there. I think because the basic drive is formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled). Is it? How to make a basic device on FAT32 or exFat? (I know how to make partitions though but  Seagate doesn't allow me to make one with a specific format) So then I can make partition and use this device on my Samsung LED too. Or should I return and buy WD Passport? I don't know what to do. I hope anyone will have good suggestions here.

Answer (score 2):

By accident I found that, by attempting to reformat my Seagate drive as FAT32 (which failed), I was then able to reformat to Mac OS (J Ex) with the partition options available… This then said it was able to work as a startup disk – not tried booting from the CCC backup yet, fingers crossed!

Answer (score 1):

Partitions are just a result of a logical splitting of a continuous disk. The partition table may have several mutually exclusive formats (e.g. Apple Partition Map or GUID).

A partition may contain a file system (e.g. ExFAT or HFS+ Journaled) or not.

Some of your devices won't be able to read a GUID (e.g your TV set) or some of the formatted volumes (e.g HFS+ Journaled can't be read by Windows system without additional drivers).

---

Save the content (if any!) of the Seagate volumes to another drive.

Attach the Seagate to your Mac and open Disk Utility:

[image: Disk Utility]

1. Choose the Seagate in the left pane
2. Hit *Partition*
3. Select *2 Partitions*

[image: Partition type]

4. Hit the button *Options…*
5. Choose *Master Boot Record*

[image: Partition size]

6. Choose appropriate sizes for the partitions by moving the slider
7. Choose a name and format for each of the partitions

   I recommend the following division.

   - 1st partition  Name: Photos Format: ExFAT
   - 2nd partition Name: Mac     Format: Mac OS X Extended (Journaled)

Finally apply the settings by hitting the button *Apply*.

Now test the external disk with all your devices.

You may have to add a third partition to get the external disk working attached to your TV set. Choose the following set up:

- 1st partition  Name: *TV*         Format: FAT
- 2nd partition Name: *Photos*  Format: ExFAT
- 3rd partition  Name: *Mac*      Format: Mac OS X Extended (Journaled)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your effort, but its not that easy. I cant select partition or write the size of my need. I cant even put my mouse there. Also you didnt mention in your first steps that what formate should I choose on basic seagate"Mac OS X Extended (Journaled), FAT or EXFAT? I erase again and hit EXFAT and MASTERBOOT RECORD. If I use masterboot or chose Mac OS X Extended (Journaled) it wont work on T.V or Windows. I want it to compatible all of them.

Comment: @Simi There is nothing like a "basic" Seagate. I don't understand this question. The "basics" of a hard disk is an unpartitioned/unformatted disk.

Comment: I mean main seagate with out partition.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your hard drive to work on your Mac and PC AND tv then you should format your hard drive to MS—DOS (Fat32). Just remember that you probably won’t be able to have movie files bigger than 4gb.

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question, since he wasn't able to partition it in the first place. In any case, exFAT solves the 4GB issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it after so many tries.

I formated drive as Mac OS X extended. Otherwise it didn't allow me to make partitions on other formates. So I made partitions journaled: one for mac and one for Photos as ExFAT.

- It works on my Samsung LED TV and Windows.
- But not working on PS3 and Sony LED.